# Help design an ad to promote the site during tax season

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I think tax season is a great opportunity to give this site some exposure and promotion, so I'd like to create a house ad that we can run elsewhere on the network.

Problem - I am not an artsy person and should not be designing anything.  Aside from that, we want you involved!

*So I need your help! (:*

If you have an idea or a mockup for an ad, please post it!  We do have a designer that can help with the ad if someone has an idea for a theme or text, but not the finished ad.

The size of the ad will be 220x250.  This would go [in the sidebar along with the other house/internal ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CWGL.png).

Here's an ad that was done for our [Parenting site](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) just as an example.

[image: sample Parenting Stack Exchange ad]

---

**What do you think would make a great ad that would draw users from the rest of our network to this site?**

Comment: I'm not sure this is the *best* way to attract people to the site; it runs some risk of flooding the site with a bunch of way-too-specific questions about each individual's tax return. Some thought should be put into how to avoid that.

Comment: @fennec The ad will *run* during tax season but need not necessarily be *about* taxes.  More people are aware of their finances when dealing with taxes, so it is a great time to advertise.  The ads really just need to be about personal finance.

Comment: @Chris I think playing off of a tax theme during tax season might be more valuable though.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Could we run more than one ad. e.g. one with a tax theme, and one with a general theme?  A general theme ad has value to run *beyond* tax season.  *Parenting* has a couple ads.

Answer (score 4):

An ad about taxes is fine (+1 for that), but *PF & Money* is about more than just taxes.  Ultimately, people want to be successful at building up their savings and investments.

So, here's one funny ad idea to put into the rotation perhaps:

Start with a cartoony rich guy, perhaps *similar* to a guy featured in a famous board game ... but different enough to be non-infringing of anybody's trademarked design.

This guy would be wearing a 1920's [top hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_hat) & suit, and holding up two big green money bags.  One of his legs would be bent, resting up on a stack of **gold bars**.

Needs a funny caption.  Insert here:  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

*(feel free to edit .. marking this community-wiki)*

Comment: p.s. if anybody has a funny caption to suggest, edit my post or add it to the comments here. Thanks!

Comment: "I don't always pose with my money, but when I do, I pose with *all of it*."

Answer (score 3):

An image that conveys the stress most people feel about preparing their taxes - with text that tells them SE can help.

[image: OH NO I FORGOT A LINE IN MY CALCULATION!]

"Don't let this happen to you this tax season! Ask your tax questions at money.stackexchange.com" (but shorter :P )

Comment: I prefer, "W2? W who?" Or, "This 1040EZ isn't very easy."

Answer (score 2):

Something in the visual style of a tax form -- with some kind of "violator" on top of it that lets people know they can turn to this site -- might be fun

Answer (score 2):

Since this was taking forever, I just made an ad and sent it to be run on the network:

[image: taxad]

And, here it is on Programmers.SE, displaying!

[image]

This ad will run until April 14th. Tadaa.